# Display scaled image on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, image-manipulation

My BlackBerry application should fetch an image from a web service and display the image as a thumbnail. Can anyone give me an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you

```
        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(fullUrl.toString(),
            Connector.READ_WRITE, true);


        InputStream is = hc.openInputStream();

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int ch;
        while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {
            // System.out.println((char) ch);
            // msg = msg + (char) ch;
            bStrm.write(ch);
        }
        bb = bStrm.toByteArray();
```

This will generate Byte Array from your web service url. here `bb` is byte array.

There are two classes that handles image in BB. `EncodedImage` and `Bitmap`, both have constructors that generate image from byte array. I recommend use Bitmap, it has easy image re size capability.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i will surely try out the solution

Answer (score 5):

petteri is right about using EncodedImage and scaleImage32().  Specifically, you'll want to use `createEncodedImage(byte[] data, int offset, int length)` with the bytes returned by the webservice.

Be aware that scaleImage32 takes 'int' arguments, but they are fixed-point numbers, in contrast to the more widely known floating-point numbers.   To get the fixed-point value you want, use the utility methods in [Fixed32](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/math/Fixed32.html)

Finally, if you don't need the original image in the BlackBerry application, you will have a better overall experience if the webservice does the scaling.  This will reduce the number of bytes transferred to the device, and it will reduce the computation done on device to scale the image.   Scaling on the server will likely result in a higher quality scaled image as well, as scaleImage32() uses a fairly basic algorithm.

Comment: Just to add to Michael's response, if you can't scale on the server and must do it in the device, you can use 5.0 APIs to do better quality scaling using Bitmap.scaleInto()

Comment: Thanks a lot...i will surely try out the solution

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally familiar with BB either but since nobody else is answering your question, check out EncodedImage class and there method scaleImage32() should return you the scaled version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i will surely check it out :)